# Amazon s3 serving and switch between multiple css stylesheets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, amazon-s3

A developer im collaborating with ran into an issue allegedly where the local path to css `css/app.css` and `css/appDark.css` cannot be assigned to a variables in a js file and used once all the css and js files are pushed to s3.

This issue was brought up by another developer. However it doesn't make sense why in the index.html the `<link rel="stylesheet" id="style" href="css/app.css">` tag works fine.

clarification and possible solutions welcomed!

Comment: Have you heard about relative and absolute paths?

Comment: Yes, and answer relative to S3 would be great!